# Netty 4.x config auto read clarification

Tags: netty

I just want to clarify when setting a channels config option from false to true for AutoRead that you must invoke a read for it to start auto-reading?

This is the code we implemented to pause the reading side which write to this handlers channel

```
    @Override
public void channelWritabilityChanged(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)
    throws Exception {
    if (ctx.channel().isWritable()) {
        outboundChannel.config().setAutoRead(true);
        outboundChannel.read();
    }
    else {
        outboundChannel.config().setAutoRead(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no need... If you use `outboundChannel.config().setAutoRead()` it will automatically trigger a read as well.

Comment: But it isn't harmful then by doing so?